# A code to replace nan values in one column which has respective values from different column(not with mean)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, null, nan

I have 2 columns A(ID) and B, relation is such that for every unique value in column A, there is a fixed value for column 2. But few values in column 2 are 'nan' values, hence I have to substitute them with corresponding values of them from column A. How to do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae1ZT.png)
So this 'nan' in B is to be replaced with 2, as it has y in col A and for y in col A value for column B is 2.
I need to do this for a larger dataset.

Answer (score 0):

try `fillna()` and specify column and value you want to replace `NaN` in as `dict`

`df = df.fillna({'B': 2})`

Or see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)